# Find email IMAP incoming/outgoing server ip and port

Tags: email, smtp, imap

My organization has own email id and can be accessed through web-browser. Now I want to setup IMAP in Gmail app in android. This requires specific incoming/outgoing server ip, port, security certificate. However, to my surprise "Mail.ru" app automatically recognizes everything (I just need to provide my email id and pass) and works perfectly (both in the organization network or outside world). These informations are also required to setup email in thunderbird. Is there any way to know this, like tracing packet, or any other way?

N.B: Nadmin don't want to share these info. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461154/figure-out-smtp-server-host) does not help much.

Answer (score 0):

Many email clients support some kind of *Autodiscovery*, where based on the domain name certain well-known URLs are tried in an attempt to download an XML document containing information about the SMTP and IMAP settings applicable for that domain.

Here is some Microsoft documentation about it:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511507.aspx

See also:

https://serverfault.com/questions/172326/how-to-configure-email-autoconfiguration-for-a-domain